# Function is returning Undefined

Tags: javascript

I need small help in a small code. The function is returning undefined and i want to return the console.log of the sum. The code is here http://jsbin.com/jedigigigo/edit?js,console

```js
var addDigits = function a(num) {
  var length = num.toString().length;
  var value = num.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(value[i]);
  }
  if (sum > 9) {
    a(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
  }
};


console.log(addDigits(38));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add return in if statement :-

```
/**
* @param {number} num
* @return {number}
*/
```

```js
var addDigits = function a(num) {
  var length = num.toString().length;
  var value = num.toString();
  var sum = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < value.length; i++) {
    sum += Number(value[i]);
  }
  if (sum > 9) {
    return a(sum);
  } else {
    console.log(sum);
    return sum;
  }
};


console.log(addDigits(38));
```

Comment: Thank you for it!

Answer (score 4):

```
 if(sum>9) {
     return a(sum); // You forgot to return a value from recursive call.
 }
```

Although the code looks really weird :)

Comment: Thank you for it!

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your code. I don't know why are calling sum recursively here. If I understood it correct then you are only trying to return sum of digits of a number (non-negative). I modified your code like below

```
var addDigits = function a(num) {
     var length=num.toString().length;
     var value=num.toString();
     var sum=0;
     for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
         sum+=Number(value[i]);
     }
     return sum;
};
console.log(addDigits(23456));
```

I updated your bin also you can check [here](http://jsbin.com/vutinevota/edit?js,console)

Answer (score 0):

```
var addDigits = function a(num) {
         var length=num.toString().length;
         var value=num.toString();
         var sum=0;
         for(var i=0;i<value.length;i++) {
             sum+=Number(value[i]);
         }
         if(sum > 9) {
             return a(sum);
         }
         else
         {
            return sum;
         }

    };

    console.log(addDigits(38));
```